# ConTeXt: How to force text to fit in a MetaFun box?

Tags: context, metafun

How to make text fit in a MetaFun box with specific width ?

[image]

For now I have

```
\startuseMPgraphic{MPBoxFrame}
  % Useful values
  numeric w, h, o, b ;
  w := 4.5cm ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
  b := 1pt ; % border size


  drawoptions (withpen pencircle scaled b withcolor blue) ;
  draw (0,h)--(0,0)--(w,0)--(w,h)--(0,h) ;


  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[MPBoxFrame][\useMPgraphic{MPBoxFrame}]

\defineframedtext[BoxFramedText][frame=off,
                                 background=MPBoxFrame,
                                 offset=\bodyfontsize,
                                 width=\textwidth]

\definestartstop[SpecificWidthBox][alternative=empty,
                                   before=\startBoxFramedText,
                                   after=\stopBoxFramedText]

\starttext
  \startSpecificWidthBox
    This is a looooooooong text that I need to fit in the box.
  \stopSpecificWidthBox
\stoptext
```

producing:

[image]

Comment: You are missing `align=normal` in the definition of `\defineframedtext`. Without a value of `align`, `\framed` acts as a `\hbox`, with a value of `align` it acts like a `\vbox`, which is what you want

Comment: Do you want the box to grow vertically so that all text is always visible, or are you okay if the text is cut off when too long? Also, are you sure that you need to use MetaFun in this case? Could this be an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Yeap, I want the box to grow vertically to get all the text. I know it's possible to do it with frames, however I would like to know how to do it with MetaFun just for the record and because I have some ideas I would like to make with as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a frame that has a background drawn using MetaFun, instead? The frame will grow as you expect and then MetaFun can draw with respect to the overlay width and overlay height values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, as @Dave Jarvis mentioned frames do the job.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{MPBox}
  draw OverlayBox 
       withpen pencircle scaled OverlayLineWidth
       withcolor OverlayLineColor;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[MPBoxOverlay][\useMPgraphic{MPBox}]

\defineframedtext[MPBoxFramed]
                 [
                   frame=off,
                   background=MPBoxOverlay,
                   offset=\bodyfontsize,
                   framecolor=red,
                   rulethickness=0.5pt,
                   width=100mm,
                 ]

\starttext
\startMPBoxFramed
    \input knuth
\stopMPBoxFramed
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: I hope that you don't mind that I have simplified the code (use `OverlayBox` instead of manually constructing the box; use `OverlayLineWidth`, and `OverlayLineColor` rather than passing these through MPvars and measures).

Comment: Great! However I would have left `\measure`s for reusability but why not!

Answer (score 4):

You can limit the width of a string with the `\limitatetext` command which takes three arguments:

1. The text you want to shorten.
2. The maximum length for your text.
3. A symbol which appears at the end of your text when it exceeds the maximum length.

[image]

In the following example the length of the text is limited to 9cm with a box which is 10cm wide.

```
\starttext

\startframed[width=10cm]
\limitatetext{This is a looooooooong text that I need to fit in the box.}{9cm}{...}
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

This produces

[image]